# Convergence of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

We are considering the series of general term: $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$

I need to find if this series converges or diverges.

1) The Alembert rule can't be applied since we find the limit equal to 1.
2) I therefore tried rewriting:

$(1+\frac{1}{n})^n= \exp(n\ln(1+\frac{1}{n}))\\= \exp(n(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2n^2}+o\big(\frac{1}{n^2}\big)\big)\\=\exp(1-\frac{1}{2n}+ O\big(\frac{1}{n^2}\big)\big)$

How can I continue from here ?

Comment: What happens to your last term when you take the limit as $n\to\infty$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}e\neq 0$$

Comment: So in my answer, I just have to take the limit as n does to infinity. And conclude convergence right ?

Comment: Of course not! What is the basic **necessary** condition for *any* infinite series to converge, @user43418?

Comment: Sorry! DIVERGENT since if a series converges then the sequence's limit is zero. Hence if the limit is nonzero, the series is non covergent ie divergent

Comment: Exactly so, @user43418

Answer (score 1):

If you really are asking whether $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (1+ \frac{1}{n})^n$ converges, that fact that $(1+ \frac{1}{n})^n > 1$ for all $n \geq 1$ should make that obvious.  You don't need to find $\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+ \frac{1}{n})^n$ or even worry about whether it exists.

Answer (score 0):

The divergence test should tell you the answer.